# how to populate a list of values in a drop down

Tags: jquery, ajax, grails

I have two select dropdowns. If I select values from one dropdown, the other should be populated with corresponding values.

```
<g:select name="firstText" from="${eventsList}" noSelection="['':'-Choose the From Date-']" onchange="categoryChanged(this.value)" />
            <label>WayBill Id</label>
            <select id="bill">
                <option>Select Bill</option>
             </select>
```

During the onchange function, I am making an AJAX call to a controller and getting the values
This is my ajax function

```
function categoryChanged(categoryId) {
    alert(categoryId)
    $.ajax({
        url:"<g:createLink url="[action:'categoryChanged',controller:'jsonComparison']" />",
        asnyc: false,
        data: {dateValue:categoryId},
        success: function(data){  
            //var retrievedValue = JSON.parse(data);
            alert("inside the success ajax function"+data)

            //$("#wayBill1").val(retrievedValue.value1)
            //$("#wayBill1").html(retrievedValue.value1)
            //$('#wayBill1 :selected').text();
            var select = $('#bill');
            select.find('option').remove();
            $.each(retrievedValue,function() {             
                    $('<option>').val(data).text(data).appendTo(select);        

           });

        } 
    });
}
```

The alert alert("inside the success ajax function"+data) is firing with the values but not able to display it in the second dropdown. The values are liist of values like [0000-00.00,0001-00.00,0002-00.07]
This is my controller class

```
def categoryChanged(){
        String firstParameter = params?.dateValue
        def reply
        def wayB = []
        wayB = JsonComparison.findAllByDateValue(firstParameter)
        println "wayBill id: "+wayB.Bill
        //reply = [status:true, value1:"${wayB.Bill}"]
        render wayB.wayBill as List


    }
```

am i rendering it correctly as JsonComparison.findAllByDateValue will be returning list of values or else i am doing it wrong while displaying it. Once i receive the response the second select becomes empty and it is not placing the values into it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
$.each(retrievedValue,function() {             
   $('<option>').val(data).text(data).appendTo(select);        
});
```

You try to iterate the 'undefined' and fill each option with an entire set of returned data.

Also I would recommend to cast the returned list in you controller into JSON:

```
render wayB.wayBill as JSON
```

And then parse this JSON with JS when populating the dropdown:

```
$(data).each(function() {
    $('<option>').val(this).text(this).appendTo(select); 
});
```

Comment: in the controller i changed to render wayB.wayBill as JSON and tried $(data).each(function() {
    $('<option>').val(this).text(this).appendTo(select); 
}); but now my alert inside the ajax success function is not firing

Comment: your suggestion helped me fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

the way you are adding options into dropdwon is to be corrected. Please see if following code helps!!!

```
function categoryChanged(categoryId) {
    alert(categoryId)
    $.ajax({
        url:"<g:createLink url="[action:'categoryChanged',controller:'jsonComparison']" />",
        asnyc: false,
        data: {dateValue:categoryId},
        success: function(data){  
            var retrievedValue = JSON.parse(data);
            alert("inside the success ajax function"+data)

            //$("#wayBill1").val(retrievedValue.value1)
            //$("#wayBill1").html(retrievedValue.value1)
            //$('#wayBill1 :selected').text();
            var select = $('#bill');
            select.find('option').remove();

            for(i=0;i<retrievedValue.length;i++)
            {
             $('<option/>', {
              value: retrievedValue[i],
              html: retrievedValue[i]
             }).appendTo('#bill select');
            };

        } 
    });
}
```

Comment: the alert inside my ajax success function is not firing now once i tried the way that you mentioned

Comment: I think the "var retrievedValue = JSON.parse(data);" is not working, put an alert above this line and See. Check if the data is coming in proper JSON format.

Comment: i am getting 0000-00.00,0001-00.00,0002-00.07 in the alert

Comment: It is not a valid JSON. Valid example: ["0000 - 00.00", "0001 - 00.00", "0002 - 00.07"]. Use http://jsonlint.com to check if ur JSON is valid

Comment: yes now in the alert alert("inside the success ajax function"+data) i am getting the value as  ['0000 - 00.00', '0001 - 00.00']

Comment: but the value is not getting inserted into the select drop down